# How to specify commands to be run before shutdown with NUT in case of power & network failure?

Tags: bash, raspberry-pi2, shutdown

I have a NAS with a usb plugged UPS on it.
I have installed nut client (only the client) on my raspberry to monitor the UPS. 
I must plug the UPS to the NAS because it's the only device which recognizes my UPS (chinese generic, unfortunately no choice in my country). 
No way to make it directly work plugged to the raspberry.
As I've installed only nut client into my raspberry, /etc/nut was empty. I've created 3 files:

nut.conf

```
MODE=netclient
```

upsmon.conf

```
MONITOR login@nas_ip 1 admin password slave
SHUTDOWNCMD "/sbin/shutdown -h now"
NOTIFYFLAG ONBATT SYSLOG+WALL+EXEC
NOTIFYFLAG ONLINE SYSLOG+WALL+EXEC
NOTIFYCMD "/etc/nut/notifycmd"
```

the notifycmd script:

```
    #!/bin/bash
#
# NUT NOTIFYCMD script

PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin

trap "exit 0" SIGTERM

if [ "$NOTIFYTYPE" = "ONLINE" ]
then
        echo $0: power restored | wall
# curl command to send me a sms
        # Cause all instances of this script to exit.
        killall -s SIGTERM `basename $0`
fi

if [ "$NOTIFYTYPE" = "ONBATT" ]
then
        echo $0: 40 minutes till system powers down... | wall
#curl command to send me a sms
        # Loop with one second interval to allow SIGTERM reception.
        let "n = 2400"
        while [ $n -ne 0 ]
        do
                sleep 1
                let "n--"
        done
        echo $0: commencing shutdown | wall
        sleep 10
        upsmon -c fsd
fi
```

My UPS is powerful enough to wait 40 minutes before shuting down the nas and the raspberry remotely.
I receive a sms when power loss and power restored.

But there is a special case: if the raspberry lost connection with the ups when it is on battery, the raspberry shut down almost immediately... I think this is a protection behavior, but i'd like to insert a curl command which sends a sms before shutdown, like "power loss and connexion failure with ups"
(i know the command itself, this is not the problem)
I know I must add something like "DEADTIME" or "NOTIFYFLAG NOCOMM" or "COMMBAD" in upsmon.conf, but not sure what to choose...
And what do i have to add in my "notifycmd" file ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may raise the value of DEADTIME, if you feel that this would be good for your Raspberry Pi. From a recent upsmon.conf:

```
# upsmon requires a UPS to provide status information every few seconds
# (see POLLFREQ and POLLFREQALERT) to keep things updated.  If the status
# fetch fails, the UPS is marked stale.  If it stays stale for more than
# DEADTIME seconds, the UPS is marked dead.
#
# A dead UPS that was last known to be on battery is assumed to have gone
# to a low battery condition.  This may force a shutdown if it is providing
# a critical amount of power to your system.
```

If you know for sure that the UPS has enough battery for your Raspberry Pi (even when you can't talk with it) you may rise DEADTIME to something like 120 (2 minutes) or even 300 (5 minutes). Just keep in mind that the value should be a multiple of POLLFREQ and POLLFREQALERT.

After this, upsmon will have some more time to run your NOTIFYCMD.
Now, just add a case for COMMBAD:

- COMMBAD is triggered as long as the communication is lost
- COMMOK is triggered as long as the communication is recovered
- NOCOMM is triggered as long as the communication has not been recovered for some time

Also, consider using the NOTIFYCMD just for notifying something, not doing the dirty job (e.g. shutting down the system).